# DC++ software for Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

[DC++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC++) and Strong DC++ are powerful applications for the PC.

I would like to know if there is an appropriate software for Mac OS X (Lion preferably) which can connect to hubs in my network.

Comment: Wow. I remember DC++. I was really into that in like 2004.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if DC++ runs well enough in VMWare (or other virtualization) solutions that map the PC and Mac home folders together or if people prefer a client compiled for OS X like [EiskaltDC](https://code.google.com/p/eiskaltdc/downloads/list?can=1&q=label%3AOpSys-OSX&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount) with open sourced code at http://code.google.com/p/eiskaltdc/

Comment: Would be nice to have brief description of what DC++ and Strong DC++ does in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

[Direct Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Connect_%28file_sharing%29) lists a couple of applications that support DirectConnect protocol. Amongst those are at least 3 native mac clients:

- [MLDonkey](http://mldonkey.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)
- [ShakesPeer](http://shakespeer.bzero.se/)
- [Jucy](http://jucy.eu/)

None of those, maybe with the exception of MLDonkey, seems to be very actively maintained though.

Answer (score 1):

I use Eiskaltdc++. I used Shakespeer before but the developement stopped and there are some annoying bugs/missing features. The only problem is Eiskaltdc++ is not retina ready. Jucy has been buggy when I used it about a year ago.

http://code.google.com/p/eiskaltdc/